# Limits of integration

Tags: classical-mechanics

In the following video can someone explain why did he take the limits of integration to be from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ ? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJWFgJTxIFk&index=9&list=PLYVDsiuOZP5pNzoB-e4ugTz96dGpspdDI

Comment: This needs additional information to make it possible for someone to answer the question without seeing the video.

Comment: I agree with @David Z; I'll not waste my net balance on seeing a video! Put the info here,if you really want help.

Comment: @DavidZ incorrect, a quick comment look was all it took.

Comment: @Zach466920 to be clear, are you saying I'm incorrect to claim that SE etiquette/policy says the question should be edited to include enough information to make it answerable without watching the video?

Comment: @DavidZ that's not quite correct. I'm saying if you don't have to watch the video then your premise is incorrect.

Comment: @Zach466920 I didn't really have a premise; all I meant was that the question should be edited to contain enough information to make it answerable without watching the video.

Comment: @DavidZ then we've made a circle, it's possible to look at the comment section of the video alone, and then answer the question.

Comment: @Zach466920 You shouldn't have to follow the link, the video can be deleted. The owners of stack exchange specifically devote their money to have questions and answers that are useful to future people. Not to archive a list of broken links. The fact that you fixate on the words "seeing the video" indicates you do not understand the actual policy. Which means you probably misunderstand other policies like not answering check-my-work problems or even the focus on physics concepts. The policies come from a single principle of having a store of useful and vetted questions and answers.

Comment: @Zach466920 I think this question might be safe since they accepted your answer and you got some votes. So I think you'd have to delete your answer before this question could be removed. And questions here are supposed to be removed for good reasons. And there are different reasons to link, sometimes it is just to show effort into trying to solve the problem yourself, which would be OK if the link rotted. In my experience many videos are deleted before I find time to watch them. Multiple videos a month. If someone gets their answer without following the rules it encourages them to do it again

Comment: @Zach466920 Which means you are making more work for people in the future. If eventually people work too hard they might stop working. At which people without moderation this can descend to a homework help site with all the picture and videos and links rotted away so the same questions have to be asked again and and again and answered again and again. And there are already sites like that, so this unique cite would be gone. And frankly SE might shut down physics SE if that happened.

Comment: @Zach466920 Frankly, since you find it so easy to include the information you could suggest an edit that includes that information, and you could even get reputation for that. (And by suggest an edit I don't mean make a comment, I mean you can click on the bottom to edit and then peer review kicks in on your edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person in the video took $\theta$ to be from the vertical axis. This was stated in the video itself.

You might be more familiar with taking an angle to measure going counter-clockwise from the 3 o'clock position. If you want to measure angles that way then you can go from $0$ to $\pi$ and this was explained by the maker of the video in the comments to the video.